# How do we make tag synonyms for phrasemes and related?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Прошу допомоги у створенні синонімів до групи теґів, пов'язаних зі сталими виразами. Наразі є декілька значень, які варто розглядати:

- [сталі-слова-та-вирази](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%96-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8)
- [усталені-слова-та-вирази](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%96-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8)
- [крилаті-вислови](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%96-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8)
- [фразеологізми](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%96%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b8)
- [phrasemes](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrasemes)
- [ідіоми](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%96%d0%b4%d1%96%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8)
- [idioms](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms)

Яке з них має бути первинним або не бути серед синонімів узагалі?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Головним тегом повинен бути [фразеологізми](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%96%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b8), phrasemes - це його переклад англійською. Інші терміни - більш вузькі, це "спеціалізовані" фразеологізми: idioms=ідіоми - їх смисл не витікає із значень слів що в них входять; крилаті вирази мають переважно літературне походження.

---

- [крилаті-вислови](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%96-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8), на мою думку, **не можуть бути** головним тегом, адже це переважно фрази літературного походження, більшість яких можна супроводити фразою "Як сказав Тарас Шевченко", "як написано у Біблії", "як казав Геракліт" ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)). Ну і оскільки у нас ще досі нема питань щодо крилатих висловів то може і не варто цей тег створювати. Може коли з'явиться більше питань по літературі це стане більш актуальним.
- [ідіоми](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%96%d0%b4%d1%96%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8) - стійкий неподільний зворот мови, що передає єдине поняття, зміст якого не визначається змістом його складових елементів.
- [фразеологізми](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%96%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b8) "(фразеологічні звороти) — стійкі (усталені) словосполучення, які сприймаються як єдине ціле і вживаються носіями мови в усталеному оформленні". "семантично пов'язане сполучення слів, яке, на відміну від подібних до нього за формою синтаксичних структур (висловів або речень), не виникає в процесі мовлення відповідно до загальних граматичних і значеннєвих закономірностей поєднання лексем, а відтворюється у вигляді усталеної, неподільної, цілісної конструкції".

  Розрізняють три типи фразеологізмів:

  - Фразеологічні зрощення.
  - Фразеологічні єдності.
  - Фразеологічні сполучення".

  (все з [вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC))

  Ще трохи [тут знайшов](http://supermif.com/aforizm/fraz.html)
- [phrasemes](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrasemes) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phraseme)) - у відповідності до вікіпедії це більш загальний термін ніж ідіома і стаття phraseme поєднана із статтею фразеологізм. У "фраземи" (фразеологізми) стаття включає ідіоми, квазі-ідіоми, слабкі ідіоми (де частина може бути заміненою на синонімічні слова), кліше  ("битва за урожай") і т.і.

З усього переліченого мені здається що в українській термінології найбільш загальним для усіх перечислених понять є **фразеологізм**, тому пропоную використовувати його як головний тег.

Comment: Чи входить у поняття «фразеологізми» поняття «усталені слова»? Бо я, власне, штучно створив теґ «усталені-слова-та-вирази» через те, що побачив [тут](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/revisions/656/2) теґ «усталені-слова» (і подумав: «нафіг нам окремо усталені-слова і усталене щось інше, хай краще буде 1 теґ»). Чи такого поняття як «усталені слова» взагалі не існує (в цьому сенсі), це вигадка автора того питання?

Comment: СУМ: http://sum.in.ua/s/frazeologhizm Фразеологізм - Усталений зворот, стійке поєднання слів, що виступає в мові як єдиний, неподільний і цілісний за значенням вислів.

Comment: Усталені слова - це не фразеологізми а "слова що давно стали частиною мови". Наприклад тут це описується: http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/420/69 "«усталене» слово — це таке слово, яке написано у словниках, і не міняється."

Comment: Усталені вирази - таке є у сенсі "фразеологізм". Наприклад є книга "Українські прислів'я, приказки, усталені вирази" http://www.twirpx.com/file/215595/

Comment: Accepted; done editing tag wiki and tag synonyms

Comment: @Artemix, оу, Ви забули мене теґнути, тому я не знав, що Ви відповіли.  Просто тоді виходить, що я дарма наробив оце [tag:усталені-слова-та-вирази] (як я казав, я штучно зробив його з [tag:усталені-слова] та [tag:усталені-вирази] ще давно) — воно лише все заплутало. Може прибрати? Чи хай буде?

Comment: @Artemix, merge робили? Взагалі, можу пройтись вручну і [tag:усталені-слова-та-вирази] повидаляти  (я ж його і наробив). Питання — чи треба?

Comment: @Artemix, можна тепер від'єднати цей теґ і він за добу зникне. (якщо його справді змерджили, а не просто зробили синонімом. якщо просто зробили синонімом, то після від'єднання буде видно скільки його насправді залишилося і можна позамінювати вручну на, наприклад, [tag:усталені-вирази].) ну, це радше пропозиція, аніж «так зробити треба» (просто я не знав, що уст.-сл. — це з іншої опери).

Comment: @Sasha Думаю хай поки повисить - може хтось до нього звик і втулить знову. А поки синонім існує - буде автоматично замінено на [фразеологізми]